# Rotating screen help

Tags: raspbian

I'm a beginner in using Raspberry Pi, and I'm using 2 monitors, one for extended screen. However, I want to make the extended screen monitor portrait. I tried to use the screen configuration to make the extended monitor portrait, but whenever I reboot it, it goes back to normal. Is there a way I can auto-start Terminal and automatically run this command? Display=:0 xrandr --output HDMI-2 --rotate right. Thank you for answering.

I tried watching tutorials in YT, but nothing works. I hope you can help me.

Comment: `Is there a way?` is not a useful question because it always has the same `yes` answer ... `how to do?` is a more useful question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can write a script and then use it on startup -- you can search for ways to run a script on startup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).